# Class' variables inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance

**I'm trying to inherit @@name and @@pass variables from app/controllers/users_controller:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ldap'
include AuthenticationsController
def save
@@name = params[:username]
@@pass = params[:password]
end
end
```

**Class where I want to use variables app/controllers/authentications_controller:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby 
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ldap'
class AuthenticationsController
host = 'ip'
port = 389

username = @@name
password = @@pass

ldap = Net::LDAP.new
ldap.host = host
ldap.port = port
ldap.auth "uid=#{username},cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=aws,dc=company,dc=com", password

if ldap.bind 
puts 'YES!'
puts ldap.get_operation_result.message 
else
puts 'NO :-(' 
puts ldap.get_operation_result.message
end
end
```

**Full trace:**

```
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:4:in `<class:UsersController>'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:69:in `controller_reference'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:59:in `controller'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:38:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
/home//.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home//.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home//.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

**Error:**

**uninitialized constant UsersController::AuthenticationsController**

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're trying to save a user_id and password as class variables.  You don't want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

i will **not** recommend to use class variable just to store user information when you have other options:-

```
 1. User a dedicated table user_ldap(any other name you want) to store and delete 
 2. Use session to store info at server side
```

Comment: I am just trying to get username and pass entered by user and send them to ldap for verification, any ideas how can I do this?